# How to pass a variable around a view with backbone

Tags: jquery, variables, backbone.js, view

I am currently writing a Backbone app and have got stuck on what seems to be a very simple problem but cannot seem to work it out.

Let's say I have a view like this (demo code)

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
         console.log('created a view');
    },
    events: {
         'click button':'buttonClicked',
         'click link':'linkClicked'
    },
    buttonClicked: function (event) {
         // I would like to store the event and pass this to the 
         // linkClicked function below when the linkClicked function is called 
         var $currentEvent = $(event.currentTarget);
    },
    linkClicked: function () {
         // When the link is clicked I would like to gain access to $currentEvent
    }
});
```

I would like to pass the variable $currentEvent to the function linkClicked when the link is clicked. Would it be best to store this in the model or can I pass the variable around the view.

Any help on this would be great!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
initialize: function () {
     /** Initialize the variable when View is first created. */
     this.currentEvent = 'something'; 
},
buttonClicked: function (event) {
     /** Assign variable when button is clicked. */
     this.currentEvent = $(event.currentTarget);
},
linkClicked: function () {
     /** Receive the value of the variable and output it. */
     console.log(this.currentEvent);
}
```

Comment: Amazing...thanks for the fast response. Didn't realise it was that simple but completely makes sense. Thanks again